# Enterprise Architect Generate DDL for package not working

Tags: database-design, enterprise-architect

I have a class diagram in Enterprise architect. I want to have database tables of the package. I right click on the class diagram package and select code Engineering --> Generate DDL.
In the "Generate package DDL" dialog, I select "Include all child packages".
The problem is in the list below, no table is added so that I can select and generate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. The problem is I wanted to generate code before generating tables. To generate tables, I had to "Transform" the package to DDL.
And then by generate code scenario, I can generate database scripts to use in sql server.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to generate DDL from a UML Class diagram in Enterprise Architect (EA) 9.3:

1. Open your project in EA
2. Open your model's class diagram in editor window. I use the Project Browser window on the right side and click on floders until I find my model and then double-click it.
3. Click Tools => Model Transformation (MDA) => Transform Current Package. This brings up Model Transformation dialog.
4. Select the classes you want mapped to DDL schema in left side of dialog (use ALL button if you want them all)
5. Click and select DDL checkbox in Transformations box on right of the dialog
6. Click Do Transform. This generate a DDL diagram.
7. Double click the DDL diagram in Project Browser and open the DDL diagram in Editor tab
8. Click Tools => Database Engineering => Generate Package DDL. This brings up the Generate Package DDL dialog
9. Select the classes you want to generate tables for by selecting Object to Generate (use Select All button if needed)
10. Specify the output file(s) in File Generation. I prefer a single file.
11. Click Generate button

This will get you the generated DDL in the specified file. I have found the generated DDL to be not usable without manual tweeks so far FWIW. It does not seem possible to specify OR Mapping strategies for inheritance, relationship mapping etc. for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at the manual.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/data_modeling/generateddlforapackage.htm) You need a database engineering model that contains a data modeling diagram. The "EAExample" sample model will show you how that looks like.

Comment: thanks for your answer observer but I knew this step, my problem was the step needed to be done before this step, before this you havo to create tables so that they can be shown in the list to generate the code.

Answer (score -1):

in version 8. I make DDL automatic package.

Select de class package > Project > Transformations > Transform Current Package
Then Select your elements for tranform > Select option (DDL) and DO Tranform.

Done